# Tensorboard directory specification and finding event files

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to TensorBoard, and I think I'm probably overlooking something simple. I am having a hard finding event files in TensorBoard. When I go to the my_logs folder, there are definitely event files, but TensorBoard claims there aren't any.

I think the issue is the format/data type of the directory I'm using as my logdir, but for my life I can't find the problem.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
%tensorboard --logdir = 'G:/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_logs'

System info: Python version 3.10.10, TensorBoard version 2.10.0
```

I have also tried converting my directory to a path object (`from pathlib import Path, dir = Path('G:/...')`) and that also don't work. I vaguely remember this working for me a while back... but not this time apparently. It also doesn't work through the Anaconda Powershell Prompt as `tensorboard --logdir = <'G:/...'>.`

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Running this to clear out previous sessions worked for me. I am in a Windows operating system where kill does not work:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
taskkill /im tensorboard.exe /f
del /q %TMP%\.tensorboard-info\*
```

This must be run every time you change directories.
Then...

```
logdir="X:\your directory\files"
```

The space in my directory is not an issue. Spaces are apparently fine. I have read that at least in past versions the ":" in a directory caused issues, but I found that this was not the case for me. Using a ":" was fine. This was extremely annoying, and I hope I have saved someone else time.